# Get the Difference between two date-time cells

Tags: google-sheets

I need to get the difference between two date-time cells in hours considering only weekdays.

Example:

```
25/02/2018 16:00:00 | 26/04/2018 09:00:00 | 19:00:00
```

Comment: What to do with 19:00:00?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried subtracting the 2 dates and setting the display option as "Difference", but got no luck there. Also tried the datedif function, but it only accepts dates (not date-time), and only returns in Days, Weeks, Months or a combination of one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using network days:

```
=(NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1)-IF(WEEKDAY(A1,2)<6,MOD(A1,1))-IF(WEEKDAY(B1,2)<6,1-MOD(B1,1)))*24
```

This says count working days from first date to second date inclusive.

If first date is a working day, subtract hours not worked before start time.

If second date is a working day, subtract hours not worked after finish time.

Strictly speaking, you should also check that start datetime is before finish datetime.

Answer (score 2):

`=(
COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA( WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&INT(B1)-int(A1)-1))+ int(A1), 2) ), "<6") 
 + IF(WEEKDAY(B1,2)<6,B1 - INT(B1),0) 
 - if(WEEKDAY(A1,2)<6,A1-INT(A1),0)
)*24`

counts:

- days not weekends, except date1 and date2
- time of day2 if not a weekend
- minus time of day 1 if not a weekend.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm always nit-picking your formulas! But according to your text, there should be a minus sign in there somewhere. I shall probably add another answer using networkdays.