# Finding a shorter period of days within a longer period for calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of dates, in total 7 periods spanning 6 months each with corresponding calculation factor.

I will have user input of period for which they'd want the calculation to be done, which can fall within one of the 6 months periods or encompass between two or more such periods wholly or partially.

Illustration:

1. The preset periods:

[image]

2. User input:

[image]

I've obtained decimal value (monthly basis) of the periods input by the user for calculation. For first instance (see user input), the decimal value for the period 01-01-2015 to 29-04-2015 will be 3.97 on monthly basis. The calculation for that period would be like:

n*3.97*113%

For the second instance, the decimal value for the period 30-04-2015 to 30-06-2015 would be 2.03, which would be used to do calculation at 113% and then the result will be added to the calculation done at 119% using the decimal value 5.65 for the period 01-07-2015 to 20-12-2015:

(n*2.03*113%)+(n*5.65*119)

Think I can handle the breaking up of periods since the revision event is bi-annual on particular dates but advice regards to that is welcome. More importantly, I need help tracing the preset calculation factor (say 132%) corresponding to the period input by the user as illustrated above. Is it feasible?

Comment: I imagine it would be possible but we'd need a bit more detail on how the calculation would work - it looks as if the second user input would specify 10 days at 132% then 6 months at 136% ?

Comment: @TomSharpe I posted the question from my smartphone, couldn't add much details and screenshots. I'll update the question in a bit with proper illustrations.

Comment: The answer is likely to be an array-type formula something like sumproduct(n*[formula for decimal number]*[formula for percentage]) . It should be possible to work out [formula for percentage] but still can't test the whole thing without knowing what n is and what [formula for decimal number] should be.

Comment: I'm guessing from your examples that decimal number is number of complete calendar months + sum (period falling in incomplete month / number of days in incomplete month)  for any incomplete months so we just need to know if n is a constant or might vary over total period of investment? Plus the result you'd expect in each case.

Comment: @TomSharpe you're right about the need for an array-type formula and I have in fact been able to get the corresponding result for the initial date (not the whole period input by the user) by using SUMPRODUCT as well as VLOOKUP and LOOKUP. While results seem good for now (http://prntscr.com/k1nm7a), I'm quite convinced that SUMPRODUCT does the best job pin-pointing the revision rate and will be useful to avoid any unforeseen anomaly. As regards the value of n, your second comment is accurate. Additionally, period will have to broken up bi-annually, which will have to be static I guess.

Comment: Of course, the problem that now remains is finding a reliable approach to calculate the user-input period with the bi-annual breakup in mind and getting accurate revision rate for the parts of that period if revision rate differs.

Comment: Ive drafted something that seems to be working, but would prefer to look at it again in the morning and do a bit more checking (am on BST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the standard approach for finding the [overlap between two dates](https://exceljet.net/formula/calculate-date-overlap-in-days) and will split the task into three parts as in my answer to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877668/get-the-difference-between-two-date-time-cells/50882375#50882375).

(1) The first part is finding the overlap between the user's range of dates and one or more revision periods in whole months and will need an array formula. I have chosen to use the [Datedif function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-datedif-function) <sup>1</sup> to get the difference in months between the beginning and end of the overlaps. If there is no overlap, the start date fed in to Datedif will be after the end date, and it will return an error which can be trapped by Iferror. If the user's dates start in A2 and B2, this gives in C2:

```
=SUM(IFERROR((DATEDIF(IF(K$2:K$8>A2,K$2:K$8,A2),IF(L$2:L$8<B2,L$2:L$8,B2),"m")+1)*M$2:M$8,0))
```

which has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

The above result includes the first and last months entered by the user even if they are incomplete months. It's then necessary to subtract any missing days in the first and last months.

(2) Missing days in first month as a fraction of the number of days in that month in D2:

```
=SUMIFS($M$2:$M$8,$K$2:$K$8,"<="&A2,$L$2:$L$8,">="&A2)*(A2-EOMONTH(A2,-1)-1)/(EOMONTH(A2,0)-EOMONTH(A2,-1))
```

A noted by OP, this could also have been done using sumproduct, vlookup or index/match.

(3) Missing days in last month as a fraction of days in that month in E2:

```
=SUMIFS($M$2:$M$8,$K$2:$K$8,"<="&B2,$L$2:$L$8,">="&B2)*(EOMONTH(B2,0)-B2)/(EOMONTH(B2,0)-EOMONTH(B2,-1))
```

The total is just (1)-(2)-(3) or

```
=C2-D2-E2
```

I have put the results of OP's two examples for comparison in H2 and H3: my results agree with them in the first 3 significant figures.

```
n*3.97*113%

(n*2.03*113%)+(n*5.65*119)
```

In all cases I have set n=1 and ignored the fact that the rate is a percentage.

[image]

---

This shows how the results would be calculated manually:

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> Pros of using Datedif:

<sup>(1) Works across year boundaries unlike just using Month function.
(2) Works conveniently with Iferror to identify non-matching date ranges.</sup>

Cons of using Datedif:

<sup>(1) It is an undocumented function and may be withdrawn in future.
(2) In this particular case, all date calculations are within the same year so Month would be useable.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tom and thanks for pointing the mistake about 119%, I fixed that in the question. I'm still wrapping my head around the answer and trying to find out as to why fractions in your results are a bit off to mine. Do they include the first and the last date of the period?

Comment: The fractions do include the first and last dates of the period. I think the differences are just because the decimal numbers in your question are only showing the first 3 figures - maybe if you could show them with more decimal places we could check that.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of output with 7 decimal places - http://prntscr.com/k23mv6
I have entered the formula for decimal value in an empty cell for reference. I had done several calculations of user inputs and the formula seemed to produce accurate results.

Comment: Well the first and fourth (that dont span multiple revision periods) are spot on. I would need more than one decimal number though when it does span multiple periods like you did in your question (n*2.03*113%)+(n*5.65*119) but with more figures. Also I cant quite make sense of the durations in your screenshot. Please note that there is a certain football match I have to watch so response may be intermittent from now on...:-)

Comment: As regards durations, I want the user to enter only first date of each period and then based on first date of next period, I calculate the period. It can be changed but I don't see the need for that. Also, it is feasible since the consecutive periods are going to be continuous without any gap in between. Please respond whenever it's okay for you to, there's no hurry. I'm looking at this weekend to finish the project.

Comment: OK, well my answer won't accommodate any changes made after the question has been posted. However I have added an extra column of manual calculation to show exactly where my results come from.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it pretty well. I'll work on it now and finish the worksheet.